# Pathfinding via an image mask using Phaser and EasyStar in Javascript - Path not found

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, path-finding, phaser-framework

I recently started learning Javascript and I just started learning Phaser. I am trying to use easystar and Phaser to create a point and click adventure game that uses pathfinding.

1- What I am trying to achieve:

I want to create a room image and then have another image that will act as a walking mask. The mask will be in a hot pink color. The player character will click on the screen and the character will walk to that coordinate as long as the character never leaves the hot pink area(Which is invisible to the user). Think of AGS(Adventure game studio) where the user imports a room image and then they draw all the area's the player can walk on.

2- How am I achieving this(or trying to):

I use the bitmapdata to load the walking mask into memory. I examine each pixel in a loop from that data and find the area's that contain the hot pink colors. I insert that data into a 2 dimensional matrix. I then use easystar to calculate a path and move the character sprite along that path.

3- The issue I am having:

It seems that either the 2 dimensional array matrix that Easystar is looking to use is not being formed correctly or I am not using easystar correctly to find a path.

4- What I need to do:

I need to either create the array correctly or use the path calculator correctly to determine what the correct path for the character sprite to take will be.

5- My code:

```
    //Set the initial game paramters - Will start with 800x600 resolution and will use WebGL as a renderer and default back to Canvas if WebGL is not present.
var game = new Phaser.Game(800,600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update});
var easystar = new EasyStar.js(); //Lets get easy star in here. 
var bmd; //This will be the object that will take the pixel data of the scene.

//Assets that will be preloaded at start
function preload(){
    game.load.image('background', 'assets/room1.png'); //The game room background that will be loaded.
    game.load.image('walkablepath', 'assets/walkablepath.png'); //The room's walkable area.
    game.load.image('maincharacter', 'assets/character.png', 32, 48); //The main characters animated spritesheet who will be walking around the room.


}

//The first function called when we start our game
function create(){
    //We are going to obtain the width and height of the background room.
    var backWidth = game.cache.getImage("background").width;var backHeight = game.cache.getImage("background").height;
    bmd = game.make.bitmapData(backWidth, backHeight); //Getting ready to determine the room size and get the pixel data of the walkable path.
    bmd.load('walkablepath'); //This will load the walkable path into memory. 
    game.add.sprite(0,0,'background'); // Will add the room background to the desktop. It will place the upper left part of the image to the upper left part of the screen.
    mainchar = game.add.sprite(200,516,'maincharacter'); // Will add the room background to the desktop. It will place the upper left part of the image to the upper left part of the screen.

    var walkableGrid = new Array(); //Lets make the grid that easy star will define as the walkable points. 
    var gridCollection;  //This will collect the 2 dimensional array grids and push it to the walkableGrid.
    var walkableRGB = "rgba(255,105,180,1)"; //This is the RGB value of the area's the user can walk on. - Hot Pink is the RGB Color
    var color; //Will contain the pixel color of where the walkablepath search index is on.

    //Following code will begin at the top left corner of the walkable area and check each pixel for the hot pink color. If it finds it, it will add a 0. If not, 1. 
    for (i = 0; i < backWidth; i++) { 

        gridCollection = "[";

        for (j = 0; j < backHeight; j++) {
        color = bmd.getPixelRGB(i, j); //Store the color date of X and Y pixel



        if (color.rgba == walkableRGB){

            gridCollection = gridCollection + "0";

        } 

        if (color.rgba != walkableRGB) {

            gridCollection = gridCollection + "1";

        }

        //If there is still more width in the image, it will add a comma. Otherwise it won't and the array can be closed off.
        if (i != backWidth) {
            gridCollection = gridCollection + ",";

        }


    }
    //Close up and then Push the Array to the walkable grid
        gridCollection = gridCollection + "]";
        walkableGrid.push(gridCollection);



      }

    bmd.destroy(); //let's destroy the walkable area path we created from view - we need to find a better way to do this process.
    easystar.setGrid(walkableGrid);  //Let's add the 2 dimensional grid array we just created to Easy star's pathfinding grid.
    easystar.setAcceptableTiles([0]); //Let's also make sure that easy star is aware that the 0 tiles are the tiles that the player can walk on.
    game.input.onDown.add(calculateWalkPath, this);



}

function update(){

}

function calculateWalkPath() {  //This function will be called every time the user clicks on a path to walk to. 
    console.log(game.input.x + ", " + game.input.y + "/");
    console.log(mainchar.x + ", " + mainchar.y + "/");
    //Now let's calculate the path and presumably use tweening to move the character from it's current x and y position to it's next calculated position
    easystar.findPath(game.input.x, game.input.x, mainchar.x, mainchar.y, function( path ) {

    if (path === null) {
        //Do something like a shrug animation from the character for not being able to find a path.
    } else {

        mainchar.x = path[0].x;
        mainchar.y = path[0].y;
        console.log(path[0].x);
        console.log(path[0].y);

    }
});

//Let's get this party started.
easystar.setIterationsPerCalculation(1000);
easystar.calculate();

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

You can look at an example I am trying to run here: http://sw-bfs.com/examples/udemy/

Comment: I'm not experienced with easystar, but it looks like your `gridCollection` object should be an array instead of a string. Replace `gridCollection = "[";` with `gridCollection = [];` and replace `gridCollection = gridCollection + "0" (or "1")` with `gridCollection.push(0 or 1);`

Comment: That worked better, but walkableGrid needs to be a 2 dimensional array and when I push each gridCollection, it just appends it rather than adds it as an additional dimenionsal array. As such, EasyStar is giving me an error.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. I just did a quick check by pushing 2 arrays, each with 5 elements, into another array, and the length was 2 and each element was an array that had 5 elements. Are you sure the walkableGrid is NOT an array containing multiple arrays (which is the definition of a 2D array, right)?

Comment: Well that is what I was trying to accomplish, a 2D array. EG: [0,0,0,0,1,0,1], [1,1,1,10,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1,0], etc... This is a 2d array, correct? or am I confusing it?

Comment: That is correct. So, if I have an array instance (like walkableGrid), and I push other arrays (like gridCollection) into that array, then walkableGrid becomes a 2-D array, so it would look like what you said, but with another pair of brackets wrapping the entire thing like this: [ [ <array 1>], [<array 2>], ... , [<array n>] ]. What is the error from EasyStar?

Comment: When I click certain spots it is telling me the clicks are out of grid when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Have you printed out your grid to see if it is coming out as expected? Just before `walkableGrid.push(gridCollection);`, call `console.log(gridCollection);` and you should get a good printout of 1's and 0's that should align with your image.

Comment: I did, but instead of being a multi-dimensional array, it pushes it out as a single array.

Comment: Okay, I think I found another issue that may be mixing up your path finding. It looks like your grid building outer-loop is incrementing in the X direction, and the inner-loop is iterating in the Y direction. I looked at the [easystarjs demo script](https://github.com/prettymuchbryce/easystarjs/blob/master/demo/static/js/easy-star-demo.js) and they are building the grid the opposite way. Make your outer loop iterate in Y direction, and inner loop iterate in X direction. (Be sure to correctly get the PixelRGB with your new loop variables.)

Comment: What that basically means is that currently, your gridCollection is representing a COLUMN of pixels in the walkable path image, but to make easystar work properly, it needs to represent a ROW of pixels. That is why I suggest changing the outer and inner loop "directions".